# MySql deletes on small amount of records in a large table are slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some issues running deletes of a small amount of records in my production database, which has large amounts of records.

My tables are:

Member: 8m records

- Index on 'id' column
- Index on 'sub_id' column

Member_child: 62m records

- Index on 'id' column
- Foreign key (an index by default???) on 'member_id' column

My application needs to delete all child records for members of a certain submission (sub_id) value, so trying to run query:

```
delete from member_child where member_id in (select m1.id from member m1 where m1.sub_id=xxx)
```

My submission in question has approximately 500 records in the child table.

The delete statement takes approx 6 mins to complete, which is not a great user experience.

When this query is running and I connect another MySQL connection and run 'show ENGINE INNODB ENGINE\G;' I can see that the query creates locks on 5m+ records:

```
---TRANSACTION 0 48901, ACTIVE 233 sec, process no 32526, OS thread id 
139811386337024 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 269
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
488961 lock struct(s), heap size 47413232, 5052181 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2, query id 140 localhost iconnect preparing
delete from member_child where member_id in (select m1.id from 
member m1 where m1.sub_id=12345)
```

I believe my indexes are correct. Any suggestions on what else I can try?

This is MySql v5.1.73 running on linux.

My 'transaction-isolation' is READ-COMMITTED (had to change this from the default so that concurrent queries for different submissions could run at the same time without one query failing with a lock timeout exception) and a 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' = 1G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need indexes.  I would be inclined to write this as:

```
delete mc
    from member_child mc join
         member m
         on mc.member_id = m.id and m.sub_id = xxx;
```

Then you want an index on `member(sub_id, id)` and `member_child(member_id)`.

Comment: Does the order on the index matter? Is member(sub_id,id) the same as member(id,sub_id)?

Comment: @shuttsy . . . Not at all.  The order in the index does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a inner join instead of in clause

and be sure you have composite index  on  memeber table as (sub_id, id)

```
delete from member_child mc
inner join  member  m1 on mc.member_id = m1.id and m1.sub_id = xxx
```